# cannot decode object of class (AMPathPopUpButton)'

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm new to `Swift` and I'm using `xCode 6 Beta 5`. My issue is I'm getting compiler error:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '***
>   -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (AMPathPopUpButton)'"

when adding `AMPathPopUpButton` to my application UI. Any one can help??

```
2014-08-17 22:17:39.285 FileSize[6633:303] An uncaught exception was raised
2014-08-17 22:17:39.286 FileSize[6633:303] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (AMPathPopUpButton)
2014-08-17 22:17:39.286 FileSize[6633:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f33025c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff93c06e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f33010c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe0dd9 _decodeObjectBinary + 2349
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe1f9f -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1774
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe219b -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 202
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe0e92 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe034d _decodeObject + 288
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff98a885ac -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 1949
    9   Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe0e92 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    10  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe034d _decodeObject + 288
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a8e438 -[NSWindowTemplate initWithCoder:] + 1043
    12  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe0e92 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    13  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe1f9f -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1774
    14  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe15d7 -[NSSet(NSSet) initWithCoder:] + 203
    15  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe0e92 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    16  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe034d _decodeObject + 288
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a60750 -[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:] + 155
    18  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe0e92 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    19  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe034d _decodeObject + 288
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a6056f loadNib + 232
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a5fb6c +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 288
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a5f95c -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 197
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a5f74b +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 357
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a5b597 NSApplicationMain + 448
    25  FileSize                            0x0000000100008f32 top_level_code + 34
    26  FileSize                            0x0000000100008f6a main + 42
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8ff585fd start + 1
)
2014-08-17 22:17:39.303 FileSize[6633:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (AMPathPopUpButton)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f33025c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff93c06e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f33010c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe0dd9 _decodeObjectBinary + 2349
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe1f9f -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1774
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe219b -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 202
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe0e92 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe034d _decodeObject + 288
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff98a885ac -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 1949
    9   Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe0e92 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    10  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe034d _decodeObject + 288
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a8e438 -[NSWindowTemplate initWithCoder:] + 1043
    12  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe0e92 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    13  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe1f9f -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1774
    14  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe15d7 -[NSSet(NSSet) initWithCoder:] + 203
    15  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe0e92 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    16  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe034d _decodeObject + 288
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a60750 -[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:] + 155
    18  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe0e92 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    19  Foundation                          0x00007fff97fe034d _decodeObject + 288
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a6056f loadNib + 232
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a5fb6c +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 288
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a5f95c -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 197
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a5f74b +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 357
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff98a5b597 NSApplicationMain + 448
    25  FileSize                            0x0000000100008f32 top_level_code + 34
    26  FileSize                            0x0000000100008f6a main + 42
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8ff585fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: problem solved and I just added framework reffrence "Automator.framework" in Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Answer (score 8):

problem solved and I just added framework reference "Automator.framework" in Linked Frameworks and Libraries (in project General Tab). see attachment ** 
[image: Automator.framework]